# Naming polymorphic relationships well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coding-style, polymorphic-associations

This question is about the *naming style* of polymorphic relationships.

My database has three types of person: a 'Company', a Client, and an Employee. Each of the three are in polymorphic relationships with tasks and events, and projects.

According to the Rails guides, this would be done like (I've omitted some classes for brevity):

```
Person.rb
has_many :tasks, :as => :taskable
has_many :events, :as => :eventable
has_many :projects, :as => :projectable # awkward names

Task.rb
belongs_to :taskable, :polymorphic => true

These lead to the rather strange:
@person = @task.taskable
```

I feel that the following would be far more grammatical and elegant... would it work, and if so, is there a reason that official sources use words like `projectable` rather than words like `owner`?

```
Person.rb
has_many :tasks, :as => :owner
has_many :events, :as => :owner
has_many :projects, :as => :owner

Task.rb
belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true

This creates the elegant:
@person_1 = @task.owner
@person_2 = @project.owner
```

Comment: I checked the Rails guide about associations and it says that: `belongs_to :taskable, :as => :polymorphic` is wrong and should be: `belongs_to :taskable, :polymorphic => true`.

Comment: @jdoe - I've corrected the code to reflect that. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 4):

I personally try to keep it as generic as possible.

So `:as => :owner` does make more sense to me.

In case of doubt, I'd just use

```
:as => :parent
```

which I've already seen in some projects.